# Problem in using Android 10 API to capture audio playbac

Tags: android, audio, playback, capture, android-10.0

I hope this message finds you well. We are writing to ask some help on Android 10 API and its new functionalities. We are trying to build an application that captures only the important parts of videos and audios without saving the whole thing.

To do that our first objective is to capture playback audio in Android 10. We have tried the following two methods:

1st Method:

We have tried to capture audio on Youtube using Playback capture API introduced for android 10  but the resultant audio file produced only silence. In the documentation, it was written that when one wants to capture an audio file on a third party application, one can use **"allowAudioplaybackCapture = true"** in the manifest. We have already used this in manifest but it did not work.

We tried this method on YouTube first. It’s very likely that YouTube prevents capturing audio playback so we tried on a local audio file. The result was the same as before.

2nd Method:

We tried to record internal audio capture with media projection which is allowed for android 5.0 to android 10 (It works fine). The problem is that it captures internal audio along with external audio i.e microphone data. When we tried to mute the external audio capture, it also muted the internal capture.

Please see the code block below to have a better idea:

https://pastebin.pl/view/b2f4ec78

We would be grateful if you can give us some pointers. We have tried every documentation that is available but we could not find any solution.